# the triangle inscribed in a circle with maximum area

Tags: circles, triangles, maxima-minima

If $r$ is the  radius of the circle, $\Delta{ABC}$ a triangle inscribed in it and  $x,y,z$ are  the angles at $A,B,C$ then how to find the triangle that has the  maximum area.

In my book it's mentioned that the 
area$=\frac12ab \sin z$ where $a,b$ are the sides opposite to $A,B$, also $a=2r\sin z, b=2r\sin z .$
Can anyone tell me how to find expression for $a,b$ and the  area mentioned above?

Comment: Are, x,y and z constant and given?

Comment: I want to know how $a=2rsinz, b=2rsinz$

Comment: 1) please check my edit of your question. 2) we dont get $x=y=z=30^{\circ}$ but $x=y=z=60^\circ$

Comment: maybe a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1298379/11206

Comment: Here is a [complete and elegant geometrical proof posted by Christian Blatter](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1403815/11206)

Answer (score 2):

If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are given then $$S_{\Delta ABC}=2r^2\sin{x}\sin{y}\sin{z}$$ if it's not so,

we'll get much interesting problem.

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be sides-lengths of the triangle.

For $a=b=c$ we have $r=\frac{a}{\sqrt3}$ and $$S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{a^2\sqrt3}{4}=\frac{3\sqrt3}{4}r^2.$$

We'll prove that $$S_{\Delta ABC}\leq\frac{3\sqrt3}{4}r^2.$$
Indeed, since $$S_{\Delta ABC}=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}$$ and
$$S_{\Delta ABC}=\frac{abc}{4r},$$ we need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}\leq\frac{3\sqrt3}{4}\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{16\left(\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}\right)^2}$$ or 
$$\left(\sqrt{\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}\right)^3\leq3\sqrt3a^2b^2c^2$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)\leq3\sqrt[3]{a^4b^4c^4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4+\sqrt[3]{a^4b^4c^4}-2a^2b^2)\geq0.$$
Now, let $a^2=x^3$, $b^2=y^3$ and $c^2=z^3$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^6+x^2y^2z^2-2x^3y^3)\geq0,$$
which follows from Schur: $\sum_{cyc}(x^6-x^4y^2-x^4z^2+x^2y^2z^2)\geq0.$

Indeed, by Schur we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^6+x^2y^2x^2-2x^3y^3)\geq\sum_{cyc}(x^4y^2+x^4z^2-2x^3y^3)=\sum_{cyc}x^2y^2(x-y)^2\geq0$$
and we are done!

Answer (score 1):

I would think of it without trigonometry and calculus: If the triangle has maximum area, then we can't make the area larger by moving a single corner.

Pick one side of the triangle as base (rotate the circle so that the base is horizontal for clearer view). Then the largest area you can get is by putting the point opposite the base as far away from from the base as possible. This happens to be halfway along the longest arc between the end points of the base. In other words, the opposite point must be exactly in the middle of the two end points of the base for the area to be maximal.

Now, if the triangle is not equilateral, there is at least one point which is not in the middle of the two others, so we can increase the area of the triangle. An equilateral triangle is the only one which cannot be increased this way, so it must be maximal.

To find the area of an equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle, the height of the triangle is $\frac32r$. This is because in an equilateral triangle, heights, medians and side bisectors coincide, and we know that

1. The center of the circumcircle of a triangle is where the side bisetors intersect
2. The medians partition one another in segmenst of ratio $2:1$
3. The $2$ part of the medians is the radius in the circle, so its length is $r$

Now you have an equilateral triangle where you know the height is $\frac32r$, so you can work out that the side length is $\sqrt3r$, which gives the triangle an area of $\frac{3\sqrt3}2r^2$.

Comment: you only proved that an equilateral triangle is a local maximum with respect to the way you change the triangle. You did not prove that this is the maximum triangle that can be inscribed in a circle.

Comment: I proved it is the _only_ local maximum. If there is only one local maximum, and the space is compact (which it is if allow degenerate triangles), then that is the global maximum.

Comment: that is true but if you  incorporate this in your proof (including a proof that the space is compact) then your proof will not be simple at all. If you omit it your proof will be incomplete and wrong.

Comment: Here is a proof that adresses the missing part: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/InscribedEquilateral.shtml#proof . It needs some calculation.

Comment: Here is a more elegant geometric  proof of the missing part in your proof. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1403815/11206

Answer (score 1):

HINT

First, I suppose only $r$ is given, otherwise it doesn't make much sense.

Since $S_{\Delta ABC}=2r^2\sin{x}\sin{y}\sin{z}$, we'll have to find the maximum of $X = \sin{x}\sin{y}\sin{z}$. Now, let's fix $z$. Then $X=\frac {\cos(x - y) - \cos(x + y)}{2}\sin z$. Since $z$ it's fixed, $x + y$ is fixed and $X$ will reach a maximum when $\cos(x - y)$ reaches a maximum, that is when $x=y$

Comment: So you proved that an isoceles triangle is a local maximum, but not that the equilateral triangle is the solution

Comment: @miracle173 Just take, let's say, x as fixed and repeat it

Comment: nevertheless there is the same problem as with the solution of Arthur

Comment: @miracle173 What problem?

Comment: check https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1403815/11206

Answer (score 0):

The maximum area will be for an equilateral triangle. Draw a radial line from each vertex to the circle's centre, to make three isosceles triangles. The central angle $θ$ is 120 degrees or 2π/3 radians. The area of each triangle is $\frac {r^2\sinθ}{2}$ and the whole area will be 3 times that.

**Edit** after a comment from @miracle173.

Why is it an equilateral triangle? Consider such an inscribed triangle with one vertex centrally at the top and a horizontal base line. The area of a triangle is height * base / 2. Now, if you move the top vertex either way, the height decreases and the base remains the same, so the area decreases.

The side lengths $a$ and $b$ can also be found from simple trigonometry

$a=b=2r\sin(θ/2)$

Comment: Why is it an equilateral triangle?

Comment: @miracle173 I have edited the answer thank you.

Comment: that's not sufficient. This is true for an isosceles triangle, too.

Comment: @miracle173 not if you put a different side as the base. Moving the top vertex upward will then increase the area. I am not going to prove what is "self evident".

Comment: see my comment to Arthur's answer. Nothing is self evident, the proof does not work.

Comment: @miracle173 the question does not ask for any proof of what the maximum area is, only how to calculate that and the side lengths. At least, it did not until you changed the question, but it was not you who asked.